# my float class is deactivating my rollover class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Thanks to the generous help of someone at stackoverflow, I was able to put different colored CSS  boxes over different  images and remove the css boxes (revealing the images) whenever there was a mouseover. this is the code i used fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/alexdickson/fyYcC/

However, I also wanted the boxes to align horizontally in a float, so (being a beginner) I put another class (called float) around the images (in class rollover) but it deactivated the rollover.

Is there a better way to implement the float than I have done below?

Thanks for your help in advance

```
<div class="float">
<div class="rollover a">
    <img src="http://blahblah.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/01/1.jpg"  />
</div>
</div>

<div class="float">
<div class="rollover b">
    <img src="http://blahblah.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/01/2.jpg"  />
</div>
</div>
<div class="float">
<div class="rollover c">
    <img src="http://blahblah.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/01/3.jpg"  />
</div>
</div>

.float
{
float: left;
width: 200px;
border: 1px solid #fff;
margin: 0 15px 15px 0;
padding: 5px 10px 10px 10px;
}
```

[image: alignment problems]

Comment: I forked your code and made some changes. See if [this](http://jsfiddle.net/B9Lby/1/) is what you wanted.

Comment: @Can't Tell I tried your code, but the rollovers are deactivated see. memeofmemes.com

Comment: @Can't Tell, well you won't see the problem now because I put in new code at the site

Comment: Great title on this post.  Suggests some deep nullification, maybe with heartbreak.  Decided not to upvote, but thanks for the lift.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add the `float` class directly to the class of the inner `div`.

Also, `float` generally isn't a very good class name. You should give it a semantically meaning name, and attach its presentation via the CSS. You are leaking CSS implementation details into the HTML.

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/alexdickson/XFBR4/).

Comment: @Alex, thanks for the fiddle. There is actually going to be 4 rows with 3 images in each row, so the solution in your fiddle wouldn't work for what I want (because your solution would just align 12 images horizontally, I think) Do you know a way to set it up so it's 4 X 3? Also, what is the disadvantage of "leaking CSS implementation details into the HTML" if they are already visible through page source code? Just curious...can't be security reason, can it?

Comment: @Micheal It's not a security reason, just that you should give them a nice semantic name such as *info-box* or something, and leave the mention of `float` in the CSS. Multiple elements floated will drop down beneath them. [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/alexdickson/YVqcG/).

Comment: @Alex thanks for the advice. I learn a lot from you on here.  If you look at the results (www.memeofmemes.com) you will see the alignment of the CSS and image is not quite perfect... Do you know a way to fix that (in time for mother's day)?

Comment: @Michael Looks perfect to me, what browser are you using?

Comment: @Alex I checked in Chrome, Firefox and Safari, they all look like the image in my OP. What browswer are you using?

Comment: @Michael Chrome 11 on OS X. But now it doesn't look good, you need to make the size of the covers bigger.

Answer (score 1):

I forked the jsfiddle you posted and was able to float them left with two rows of 3 images. You can just add more to each container for more horizontal images, and add more containers to add more rows. http://jsfiddle.net/robx/592ba/1/

Comment: Thanks, I got a solution above already but also learned from yours. thank you.